# c# uwp animation make text flicker

Tags: c#, animation, uwp, flicker, marquee

I am creating a marquee animation for textblock. I have managed to do it with doubleanimation moving textblocks on canvas. But the problem is that text is flickering while moving each 0,5 seconds...

Here is the sample code I am using:

```
        sb1 = new Storyboard();
        DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames animationKeyFrames = new DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames();

        var keyFrameStart = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
        keyFrameStart.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(0));
        keyFrameStart.Value = TextWidth;

        var keyFrameEnd = new EasingDoubleKeyFrame();
        keyFrameEnd.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10000));
        keyFrameEnd.Value = -TextWidth;

        animationKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(keyFrameStart);
        animationKeyFrames.KeyFrames.Add(keyFrameEnd);

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animationKeyFrames, "(Canvas.Left)");
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animationKeyFrames, textBlock1);

        sb1.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        sb1.Children.Add(animationKeyFrames);

        sb1.Begin();
```

Does anyone knows any property, some double buffer or something like that to override this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this issue was more related to device performance. I've checked your code, there's no problem in your code.

I tested your code on different configuration of the machines. The "flicker" phenomenon was different.

There's a workaround for you to alleviate this issue.

You could alleviate this issue by setting more large duration (e.g, `keyFrameEnd.KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(20000));`).